# designing complex data structure's dependences

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm in the process of designing a finite element library. For a given problem, the finite element mesh used can have elements of different dimensions (for example tetrahedra and triangles), and combining different elements of the same dimension is also possible (for example tetrahedra and hexahedra). Therefore, I need a data structure that stores the finite elements' information. The most fundamental information is the elements' connectivity (the node IDs that define the element). For example, I need to store somehow that triangular element 4 is connected to nodes 5, 6, and 10.

My first attempt was to create a list whose index is the dimension (0,1,2 or 3) and that stores dictionaries. These dictionaries have string keys (identifiers) and the values are numpy arrays (each row representing an element connectivity). I need to do this because the numpy arrays for a given dimension have different shapes depending on the string identifiers.

This is the class:

```
import os
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy.ma as ma

flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

class ElementData(list):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.reset()
        super(ElementData, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __iter__(self):
        for k, v in self[self.idx].items():
            for i, e in enumerate(v):
                yield (k,i,e) if not ma.is_masked(e) else (k,i, None)
        self.reset()


    def __call__(self, idx):
        self.idx = idx-1
        return self

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index >= len(self):
            self.expand(index)
        return super(ElementData, self).__getitem__(index)

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if index >= len(self):
            self.expand(index)
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Element dimensions present: {}\n".format([i for i in range(len(self)) if self[i]]) + super(ElementData, self).__str__()

    def keys(self):
        return flatten([list(self[i].keys()) for i in range(len(self))])

    def reset(self):
        self.idx = -1
        self.d = -1

    def expand(self, index):
        self.d = max(index, self.d)
        for i in range(index + 1 - len(self)):
            self.append(OrderedDict())

    def strip(self, value=None):
        if not callable(value):
            saved_value, value = value, lambda k,v: saved_value
        return ElementData([OrderedDict({k:value(k, v) for k,v in i.items()}) for i in super(ElementData, self).__iter__()])


    def numElements(self, d):

        def elementsOfDimension(d):
            # loop over etypes
            nelems = 0
            for v in self[d].values():
                nelems += v.shape[0] if not isinstance(v, ma.MaskedArray) else v.shape[0] - v.mask.any(axis=1).sum()
            return nelems

        # compute the number of all elements
        if d == -1:
            nelems = 0
            for i in range(self.d+1):
                nelems += elementsOfDimension(i)
            return nelems
        else: # of specific dimension only
            return elementsOfDimension(d)
```

The class works nicely, and it allows me to loop seamlessly through all items of a particular dimension. However, there are other data associated with each element that's stored separately, for example its material. Therefore, I decided to use the same data structure to refer to other properties. To that end I use the `strip` function of the class, to return me the entire structure without the numpy arrays.

The problem that I is that the original data structure is dynamic, and if I change it, I have to modify every other structure that depends on it. I really think I went in the wrong direction while designing this class. Perhaps there's a simpler way to approach this problem? I thought about storing the extra information next to the numpy arrays (as tuples for example), but I don't know whether this is good or not. The choices made while designing software can really make our life miserable later, and I'm starting realize this now.

**UPDATE**

Using the class above, one example could be the following:

```
Element dimensions present: [0, 1, 2]
[OrderedDict([('n1', array([[0],
       [1],
       [3]]))]), OrderedDict([('l2', array([[1, 2]]))]), OrderedDict([('q4', array([[0, 1, 5, 4],
       [5, 1, 2, 6],
       [6, 2, 3, 7],
       [7, 3, 0, 4],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]]))])]
```

where the data structure has been used to store elements of 0 (node), 1 (line) and 2 (quadrangles) dimensions.

Comment: Would probably help to understand why you designed this data structure like that initially. What problem are you solving?

Comment: I'm creating a finite element library. Each row in those numpy arrays is an element connectivity (the node IDs that define the element). For a given problem, the finite element mesh used can have elements of different dimensions (for example tetrahedra and triangles), and combining different elements of the same dimension is also possible (fits example tetrahedra and hexahedra. But this first data structure deals only with elements' connectivities. Each element is also assigned a material property (for which I need another data structure for storing materials), and the same for other data.

Comment: Please provide some data to your Question that show the **change**, one that works with the given `class` and one changed that don't fit. My first attempt failed with missing `ma.MaskedArray`, where dit it come.

Comment: @stovfl I don't understand your request. But I see your attempt has failed perhaps because this class could also deal with masked arrays. So you have to `import numpy.ma as ma`. I will edit my question.

Comment: Please read this I have requested for: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @stovfl it's really not possible for me to provide you with an example since the code above is a component of a much bigger library. However, I have edited my question to add one simple result of using this class, which I output using the `print` function. I hope that will be enough.

Answer (score 2):

> **Comment**: the design goes against the logical structure of the program.

I used the given Element data example and didn't expect to get the whole picture at once.

> **Comment**: Each element has a unique dimension
>       (a triangle has always dimension 2,
>        as a tetrahedron has always dimension 3 and
>        a node dimension 0).

Sorry, I misinterpreted from the question "... elements of different dimensions..." with
"Element **have** different dimensions". I adapted my Proposal.

> **Comment**: ... the problem arises when I modify the data structure
>       (for example by adding elements)

As long as you don't show a Data example for this problem,
I can't thinking above a solution.

---

My Proposal:

```
class Dimension(object):
    """
    Base class for all Dimensions
    Dimension has no knowledge to what the data belongs to
    """
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        pass

class Element(object):
    """
    Base class for all Elements
    Hold on class Dimension(object):
    """
    def __init__(self, dimension=None):
        pass

class Triangle(Element):
    def __init__(self, dimension):
        super().__init__(dimension=dimension)

class Tetrahedron(Element):
    def __init__(self, dimension):
        super().__init__(dimension=dimension)

class Node(Element):
    def __init__(self, dimension):
        super().__init__(dimension=dimension)
```

**Usage**: Building your example Element

```
node = Node(dimension=[0,1,3])
line = Triangle(dimension=[0,2])
quad = Tetrahedron(dimension=[[0, 1, 5, 4], [5, 1, 2, 6], [6, 2, 3, 7], [7, 3, 0, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

New Future Element, only to show `class Element` could extended:

```
# New future dimensions - No changes to class Element() required
class FutureNodTriTet(Element):
    def __init__(self, dimension):
        super().__init__(dimension=dimension)

future_NTT = FutureNodTriTet(dimension=[0, (1,3), (4,5,6)])
```

Please comment if this is closer to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though interesting, the design goes against the logical structure of the program. Each element has a unique dimension (a triangle has always dimension 2, as a tetrahedron has always dimension 3 and a node dimension 0). The structure I designed works quite well. However, as I said in the question, the problem arises when I modify the data structure (for example by adding elements), because all data is scattered (materials are kept in a different data structure). I guess what I need is to keep the data together.

Comment: @aaragon: Updated my Answer to your comment

Answer (score 0):

When said "Complex data structure's dependences", you probably may speak about "graph", did you double check if any existing [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) fit your needs ? (like "Route problems")

Comment: I am more than familiar with graphs, and these are definitely not the data structure I need here.